# Using goroutines to iterate through file indefinitely

Tags: loops, file, go, iteration, goroutine

I'm new to Go so please excuse my ignorance. I'm attempting to iterate through a bunch of wordlists line by line indefinitely with goroutines. But when trying to do so, it does not iterate or stops half way through. How would I go about this in the proper manner without breaking the flow?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)


var file, _ = os.Open("wordlist.txt")
func start() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
       fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }

}

func main(){
    for t := 0; t < 150; t++ {
        go start()
        fmt.Scanln()
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: ```for t := 0; t < 150``` what's the meaning of this line?

Comment: I was attempting to spawn multiple goroutines that would iterate through the text file infinitely until a condition was true. I didn't word it right, sorry!

Comment: try waitgroups https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `file` as a global variable. Sharing read/write file state amongst multiple goroutines is a data race and will give you undefined results.

Most likely, reads start where the last read from any of the goroutines left off. If that's end-of-file, it likely continues to be end-of-file. But, since the results are undefined, that's not guaranteed. Your erratic results are due to undefined behavior.

Here's a revised version of your program that declares a local `file` variable and uses a `sync.Waitgroup` to synchronize the completion of all the `go start()` goroutines and the `main` goroutine. The program checks for errors.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

func start(filename string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, t int) {
    defer wg.Done()

    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    lines := 0
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines++
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(t, lines)
}

func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    filename := "wordlist.txt"
    for t := 0; t < 150; t++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go start(filename, wg, t)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Yes, but, as my answer illustrates, why using goroutine at all in this case?

Comment: @VonC: The OP said "I'm attempting to iterate through a bunch of wordlists line by line indefinitely with goroutines." I assume "a bunch" means that he has several wordlists to iterate concurrently. The OP's code is clearly a MRE and not the actual code. For example, using `fmt.Scanln()` to temporarily halt execution, likely for debugging.

Comment: Agreed. That is why I mentioned https://play.golang.org/p/EUB0K2V7iT as an example of concurrent list scanning.

Comment: @VonC: Wow! That's a complicated example (https://play.golang.org/p/EUB0K2V7iT) that doesn't directly address the OPs question: Why is my code not working?

Comment: Sure: I did explain why the OP's code is not working: lack of synchronization. But also, in the OP specific case, no need for goroutine.

Comment: @VonC: I'm not sure what the point of this conversation is. I posted an answer, I see you posted an answer. The OP can decide whether either of them is helpful.

Comment: @rocka2q thank you so much!